# PhantomJS cannot find an element, where Chromedriver can

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I realise that this question is very similar to [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/585), and other SO questions. However, I've played around with the screen size, and also the wait times, and that has not fixed the problem.

I am

1. starting a driver
2. opening a website and logging in with Selenium
3. scraping specific values from the home page

This is the code that isn't working in PhantomJS (but works fine if I use chromedriver):

```
time.sleep(60)
driver.set_window_size(1024,768)
todays_points = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/a[contains(text(),'Today')]/preceding-sibling::span")
total = 0
for today in todays_points: 
    driver.set_window_size(1024,768)
    points = today.find_elements_by_class_name("stream_total_points")[0].text
    points = int(points[:-4])
    total += points
driver.close()
print total
```

The HTML that I'm trying to access is inside a div element:

```
<span class="stream-type">tracked 7 Minutes-Recode for <span class="stream_total_points">349 pts</span></span>
<a class="action_time gray_link" href="/entry/42350781/">Today</a>
```

I want to grab the '349 pts' text. However, with PhantomJS the value returned is always 0, so I think it's not finding that element.

---

EDIT: When I print the html source using `print(driver.page_source)` I get the correct page outputted but the element is not visible. Checking on chrome using the view source tool, I can't see the element here either (but I can with inspect element). Could this be why PhantomJS cannot access the element?

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot to see if the element actually exists on the page? Have you printed the page source to see if it exists?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. See edit above.